# Mozilla opacity: 0 is not working

Tags: html, opacity, mozilla

I am looking for solution, but can't find anywhere. I have block and I have other block under it. The first block has style "opacity: 0". So he is at the top of the other block and in that block (which opacity is 0) has few elements. The problem is there, that mozilla opacity: 0 accepting as display: none and i don't know why is that.

[image]

any solutions?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You cannot see something that is fully transparent.

Comment: yes, but I can push on the elements (at the block with black borders). opacity should make the block with red borders invisible, not hide it at all

Answer (score 0):

If you set the opacity of the parent to 0, then all his elements will be hidden.
Maybe tell us what are you trying to do and we'll try to find a better idea that will answer the terms.

Comment: the problem is that I can push elements that are under the block (with red borders). that shouldn't work

Comment: @baitas212123 Do you mean that the div behind got disappear?

Comment: no, the div with red borders got disappear at all with mozilla when i make his opacity 0. Not makes invisible, but disappearing at all

Comment: @baitas212123 ok. so you're saying that it happens only in mozilla.
upload you code to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please to see what is going on.

Comment: sure, open this with mozilla and with chrome, you will see the different http://jsfiddle.net/5zWZe/1/

Comment: @baitas212123 the controller?

Comment: yes. it should not work, becouse there is an overlay at the iframe. With chrome everything is okey, but with mozilla the overlay is missing

Comment: @baitas212123 except the fact that the controller is hide in mozilla it's working well.
the overlay block the player for both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39027/discussion-between-baitas212123-and-dvir)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your [JSFiddle - jsfiddle.net/5zWZe/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5zWZe/1/) doesn't use opacity. So this example seems unrelated to your question.

For an example with a button covered by a div, see this [JSFiddle - jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/2/). As you can see, the button isn't accessible through the div, even if you reduce the opacity to 0. Also note, the behaviour is the same in either Firefox or Chromium.

It seems, you have a special case with an iframe and flash video. See this other [JSFiddle - jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/3/) with identical CSS, but the button replaced by an iframe. Here the flash video is accessible, although the div is above the iframe. But again, same behaviour in Firefox and Chromium.

Covering the iframe/flash video with the div seems to work, when you modify the query string of the youtube URL and append `?wmode=transparent`

```
<iframe id="without" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5f-n3-pV81A?wmode=transparent"></iframe>
<div id="opacity">opacity</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle - jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/X7S3w/4/) for a working example. Now the div blocks the flash video successfully. And again, this works identically in Firefox and Chromium.

So it seems this is more a flash issue, than some CSS opacity behaviour.

Comment: see the comments at the first answer